# IETF Recommendations for preparation for PQC- clarify in what way they are referring to bits

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography

Which bits are being referred to when it is said by the IETF, "Continue to avoid baking-in algorithms, either explicitly or implicitly (e.g. via maximum field sizes)" ?

Does that mean leave enough bits of RAM (bit usage within memory for the functions to run), or sufficient key sizes as in, don't just focus on NIST level 1, 128-bit encryption but allocate for the possibility of having to use a 256 bit encryption, which requires lots more bits?

Obviously, increasing NIST levels uses more bits, but I want to be clear on what is meant, exactly, because there is a large variation between bits used among the Level 1, 128-bit lattice-based asymmetric keys proposed solutions in round 2, and an even bigger difference in bits used in 256-bit keys proposed.

I am comparing how many resources to consider allocating on different types of systems with different proposed round 2 schemes, for resource-deprived systems, so need to go by bits reserved for the new quantum resistant schemes vs the current ones. Therefore it makes a big difference and want to make sure I understand which "bits" are being referred to.

[IETF mtg in 2017](https://www.youtube.com/watch?reload=9&v=abmd1n5WUvc&list=PLC86T-6ZTP5jdbiwi5ggLNnwLn1-r0M4h) @ time 59:29, and in the NSA recommendations it says to leave large enough bit sizes

Comment: Welcome! Apparently, people here are not able to understand what you are asking. Could you edit your question to make it more clear?